# ¿como hacer que php pegue bien el salto de linea?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo mi primer sitio web, es un blog personal, mi problema va cuando salvo un Textarea en mi DB, el mismo se salva con su correspondientes altos de  linea /r/n, pero al hacerle el echo o print aparece el salto de pagina literalmente escrito como /r/n.

```
 require('../cone/conexion.php');
            $consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM entrada_blog WHERE id_ent = ?");
            $idConsulta = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['id']);
            $consulta->bind_param("i",$idConsulta);
            $consulta->execute();
            $res = $consulta->get_result();
            $consulta->close();

            //print_r($res);
            //print_r($res->num_rows);
            
            if(($res->num_rows)>0){
                
                $cParrafo = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM parrafo_blog WHERE id_entrada_blog = ? ORDER BY orden");
                $cParrafo->bind_param("i",$idConsulta);
                $cParrafo->execute();
                $parrafos = $cParrafo->get_result();
                $cParrafo->close();

                ?>
                <div class="entrada">
                <?php
                $tittle = $_GET['titulo'];
                require('../activos/header.php');
                ?> <div class="container"> <?php
                while($resFilas = $res->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <div id="pPal">
                        <p><?php echo $resFilas['imagen_central']; ?></p><!-- cambiar a imagen -->
                        <p><?php echo $resFilas['foto_footer']; ?></p>
                        <p class="parra-ppal"><?php echo $resFilas['texto']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                <?php
                } // fin while

                if(($parrafos->num_rows)>0){
                    while($fParrafos = $parrafos->fetch_assoc()){
                        ?>

                        <div class="pSecundario">
                            <h3><?php echo $fParrafos['sub_titulo']; ?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $fParrafos['imagen_parrafo']; ?></p>
                            <p><?php echo $fParrafos['texto']; ?></p>
                        </div>

                        <?php
                    } //fin while
                }

                ?> </div></div>
```

el resultado pegado en HTML es el siguiente:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic sequi laborum dolores. Voluptatibus asperiores saepe accusantium ipsum! Architecto nobis illo perspiciatis cumque ab reprehenderit, voluptatibus, incidunt recusandae laudantium accusamus at.\r\n Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum adipisci quibusdam, nostrum cupiditate doloremque placeat! Veritatis eum debitis delectus. Deleniti architecto vel totam, nobis sequi modi ab quisquam quod molestias?

observese el salto de linea tal cual escrito, ya intente nl2br, convertirlo a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función *nl2br()*

```
echo nl2br($fParrafos['texto']);
```

Si no te funciona, prueba a sustituir los carácteres con la función *str_replace()*

```
echo str_replace('\r\n','</br>',$fParrafos['texto']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre una respuesta en https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/634196#11029006 utilizando:

```
$texto = str_replace('\r\n', "<br/>", texto);
```

Comment: Para que `PHP` reconozca el salto de línea (`\n`) y/o el tab (`\t`), es necesario utilizar comillas dobles (`"`), es decir, `"\r\n"`. De lo contrario buscará los caracteres exactos.